# Automate creation of custom user flow attributes Python Azure B2C

Tags: python, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-app-registration, msal

So far success in getting existing custom user flow attributes with Microsoft Graph in Python

```py
import msal

# Replace with your Azure AD B2C configuration
tenant_id = 'tenantID'
client_id = 'appID'
client_secret = 'secret'
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'

# Create a confidential client application
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_credential=client_secret,
    authority=authority
)

# Acquire a token
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'])
access_token = result['access_token']

# Make a request to retrieve custom user attributes
import requests

graph_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identity/userFlowAttributes?$filter=userFlowAttributeType eq 'custom'"

response = requests.get(graph_url, headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'})

if response.status_code == 200:
    result = response.json()
    print(result)
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
```

How to automate the creation of custom user flow attributes like age with `int` type without Portal using Microsoft graph in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign **`IdentityUserFlow.ReadWrite.All`** permission in your application, that is required for creating custom user attributes:

[image]

Now, modify your code to run **POST** request in order to create custom user attributes like this:

```py
import msal
import requests

tenant_id = 'tenantID'
client_id = 'appID'
client_secret = 'secret'
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_credential=client_secret,
    authority=authority
)

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'])
access_token = result['access_token']

body = {
    "displayName": "Age",
    "description": "Your age",
    "dataType": "int64",
}

graph_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identity/userFlowAttributes"
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

response = requests.post(graph_url, json=body, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 201:
    print("Custom attribute created successfully!\n")
    result = response.json()
    print(result)
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where **custom** user flow attribute created successfully:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Create identityUserFlowAttribute - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/identityuserflowattribute-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Error: 400 {"error":{"code":"AADB2C","message":"The 'identityUserFlowAttribute' field is invalid in request. Please check the request body and parameters.","innerError":{"correlationId":"151c5ada-e13d-4dcf-a847-a6511b3d8722","date":"2023-09-25T11:17:14","request-id":"3e50747e-d8bb-49a8-b3fc-82c67013e45d","client-request-id":"3e50747e-d8bb-49a8-b3fc-82c67013e45d"}}}

Comment: Could you include what you are passing in request body and parameters?

Comment: In my case, I got _same error_ when I run the code with `int` as value for "dataType" parameter like [this](https://i.imgur.com/3JVIy98.png). Make sure to pass `int64` as   "dataType" parameter's value as I mentioned in above answer to resolve the error.

Comment: `int64` did the trick! thanks

Answer (score 1):

To create a new user attribute via the Microsoft Graph API, you should send a `POST /identity/userFlowAttributes` request with the following headers:

- Authorization: Bearer {token}
- Content-Type: application/json

Body:

```
{
  "displayName": "FaveNumber",
  "description": "Your favourite maths number",
  "dataType": "int64"
}
```

See: [Microsoft Learn Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/identityuserflowattribute-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Note, although this will create the user attribute, it will not update your user flows automatically to collect/return the attribute.

Comment: Error: 400 {"error":{"code":"AADB2C","message":"The 'identityUserFlowAttribute' field is invalid in request. Please check the request body and parameters.","innerError":{"correlationId":"151c5ada-e13d-4dcf-a847-a6511b3d8722","date":"2023-09-25T11:17:14","request-id":"3e50747e-d8bb-49a8-b3fc-82c67013e45d","client-request-id":"3e50747e-d8bb-49a8-b3fc-82c67013e45d"}}}

Comment: datatype should have been `int64`, updated